# Setting the name of a text file to a variable in qt

Tags: c++, qt, datetime, qfile, qtextstream

I'm exporting data to a text file in qt every time a run a code. With my current code that file is overwritten each time. My question is how can I set the title to be a variable eg pulse_freq, this way new files will be created based on my variable values. I just can't get the syntax right.

Is there a way to put my files in a folder in the same directory as my build files? I need my code to be cross platform and if I use the full path name it's apparently incompatible with any non-windows OS. If I just name the files there'd be too much clutter in the folder. Relevant code is below:

```
// Export to data file
        QString newname = QString::number(variables.nr_pulses);
        QString filename = "C:/Users/BIC User/Documents/BIC Placement Documents/QT_data/Data.txt";
        QFile file( filename );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use something along lines:

```
QString s1 = "something";
QString s2 = " else";
QString s3 = s1 + s2;
```

`QString` concatenation with overloaded `operator+` works like charm.

And about referencing folder you're in, instead of hardcoding its path, use `QDir::currentPath()`

Thus, your `filename` creation should look like the following:

```
QString folder = QDir::currentPath();
QString file = QString::number(variables.nr_pulses); //or whatever else you want it to be
QString extension = ".txt" // or whatever extension you want it to be

QString full_filename = folder + file + extension;
```

In order not to mess with appending string after the extension, just separate it into another `QString` and concatenate those 3 elements as above (folder + file + extension).

Comment: I tried that method before but the file produced is longer a .txt file. The extension changes to TXT(variable value)

Comment: Thanks, the extension works, nice idea. However when I use the current path method the text file doesn't appear in the build folder or the project's path.

Comment: @Duanne - that's weird, for me it works with file created in build folder. Did you manage to find the file elsewhere?

Comment: No, I couldn't locate it. It worked on another PC, guess it was a bug on mine. Thanks again